# TypeError: sumEach() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nums'

Tags: python

Getting a NameError of "add" not found:

```
import math
import statistics

def main():

    numbers = str(input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")).split()
    nums = list(map(int, numbers))

    print ("Original List", nums)
    print ("Sum of list: ", add)
    print ("List squared", squared)

def sumEach(nums):
    squared = []
    for i in range (1, 6):
        squared.append(i ** 2)
    return squared

def sumList(nums):
    add = sum(nums)
    return add

main()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa may help

Comment: You don't have any variable `add` defined in `main()`. What do you think it should print?

Comment: Where are you even calling `sumEach`?

Comment: Well, there's no variable named "add" in your `main` function, so what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `sumList` and `sumEach`, not just use the name they would use to return a value if you *had* called them.

```
print ("Sum of list: ", sumList(nums))
print ("List squared", sumEach(nums))
```

Each call needs to be passed a list of numbers to work with, which would appear to be the cause of the error you mention in the title.